# How to publish a build on Google Cloud Build to Google Container registry using yaml file

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry

I have a yaml file that builds the image. The image was successfully built using the github trigger where I got the confirmation as follows:

```
Successfully built cd57cea98cac
Successfully tagged gcr.io/my-project/quickstart-image:latest
PUSH
DONE
```

It also says the push is done though I don't know if it means the push to Google Container registry since I cannot find that image on the project's Google Container registry.

This is the yaml file I used to build it:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  env:
    - 'ACCESS_TOKEN=$ACCESS_TOKEN'
  args:
    - build
    - "--tag=gcr.io/my-project/quickstart-image"
    - "--file=./twitter/dax/processing_scripts/Dockerfile"
    - "--build-arg=ACCESS_TOKEN=${ACCESS_TOKEN}"
    - .
```

Is there anything I am missing to push it to Google Container registry since I cannot see the image on GCR.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my own question.

I had missed out the image step that would push it to Google Container registry.

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  env:
    - 'ACCESS_TOKEN=$ACCESS_TOKEN'
  args:
    - build
    - "--tag=gcr.io/my-project/quickstart-image"
    - "--file=./twitter/dax/processing_scripts/Dockerfile"
    - "--build-arg=ACCESS_TOKEN=${ACCESS_TOKEN}"
    - .
images:
- 'gcr.io/my-project/quickstart-image'
```